# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError when hit the jsp

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

I have code, in which I have package called:

```
package com.test.core.it;
```

All classes inside this package only. There is a `.jsp` file, which has this line of code:

```
test.executeAllTestCase();
```

the `test` is an instance of `TestA` which is in the package `com.test.core.it`. `executeAllTestCase` has line like:

```
TestB.getInstance()
```

`TestB` is also in same package.

I builded the war and deployed to tomcat. When hit the url:

```
http://localhost:8080
```

the `jsp` is getting called, which is throwing me the exception:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.test.core.it.TestB
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:912)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:841)
```

I'm not sure, where I'm making mistake.

#### Edit

I can see the classes are loaded in `WEB-INF`->`classes`->`<package wise directory>` -> `TestA.class, TestB.class`

Comment: Is TestB class in your war in either jar file in lib or in class folder with the proper folder as package?

Comment: Have you imported `com.test.core.it` in your jsp? Or maybe an exception during static initialization of class TestB ?

Comment: @almasshaikh: Ya it is there, see my updated question

Comment: @Joachim: Ya I have imported. What do you mean by exception during static initialization of class TestB

Comment: First time. when java loads a class, the static initializers are performed. If you have a exception in this,
java will not try again to load the class definition, instead a NoClassDefFoundError is thrown. So maybe there is an oversight exception before the first NoClassDefFoundError.

Comment: I dont have any static initialization, except `private static TestB self = new TestB();`

Comment: Is this an empty contructor? If not, you could cover the code in an try catch to print out possible errors.

Comment: @Joachim: Great, static was a problem. Thanks a ton, you can answer it I can accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe an exception during static initialization of class TestB. 
First time. when java loads a class, the static initializers are performed. If you have a exception in this, java will not try again to load the class definition, instead a NoClassDefFoundError is thrown. So maybe there is an oversight exception before the first NoClassDefFoundError

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens if either at runtime the class is not found:
 - make sure your classpath contains the jar.
or two classes with the same name exists on the classpath, in this case the JVM does not know which class to load.

- check your classpath and make sure it is the same as your classpath during compile time.